# Nesting Bootstrap progress bars in Bootstrap grid system, problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I'm doing a landing page for a client and I'm really good at using the *Bootstrap* framework, however, when I nested 4 progress bars in a `col-sm-6` it didn't display the other 3. And within the other `col-sm-6` (within the `row` class), it displays, but underneath.

I think it may be something to do with the floats.

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<div class="index-skills">
    <div class="container" style="display:block !important; width:100% !important; margin-left:auto !important; margin-right:auto !important; text-align:left !important; padding:15px 30px 15px 30px !important;">
        <h2>WHY CHOOSE US?</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me into this.

Comment: you're using `col-sm-6` inside `row` and another `col-sm-6` outside of it ? I think you want something like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/td448gLu)

Comment: no, no, check out my code below. Sorry I'm new to Stack!

Comment: do you want bars side-by-side or what ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay then, follow my *Fiddle* :)

Comment: There is nothing there that points to a fiddle???

Comment: (facepalm), check my very first comment, in the end of that you can find it.